# Approaching concepts involving graphs in analysis

Tags: real-analysis, notation, problem-solving

At least in undergraduate algebra, we can discuss the properties of algebraic structures and their elements without losing generality with notation such as let $G$ be a group and $g\in G$. In using this notation we can manipulate the symbols and determine properties that hold for algebraic structures with certain conditions.

When talking about graphs and certain properties they have in analysis, it seems more difficult to create this sort of notation given that the moment you put pencil to paper and draw you immediately lose generality by giving the graph a certain shape.

Given this roadblock, how do you approach learning analysis concepts which make more sense visually, yet do not have some arbitrary representation?

Comment: Could you give an example of one of these concepts? Maybe the Intermediate Value Theorem? Or are you more interested in something higher-level?

Comment: Equicontinuity would be an example of such a concept

Comment: Equicontinuity is an interesting example. For this one I don't think in pictures so much as I think in terms of known definitions. For instance, (in particular I'm thinking of the real-valued case here) one can use pictures to develop intuition about a function being "continuous" and "uniformly continuous". Now I think of an equicontinuous family as being "uniformly uniformly continuous" in that given an epsilon the same delta works for all x and y in your space for all functions in your family simultaneously. The moral is to reduce to a level where pictures work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put simply, for me at least, it depends on the behaviour I'm investigating! For many cases I simply draw a nice, curvy, cubic-like graph, and often this is enough. You shouldn't get too hung up on the lack of generality when trying to gain intuition about things. The most important thing to ask is: why stop at one picture? If you draw one graph and don't understand the behaviour, play around, try some radically different types of picture and see if any new insights come to light. The point of the picture should be to allow you to understand the specific examples presented so that you may more easily apply the rule in general.

A related concept arose between my friends when we studied topology. With so many different topological spaces to choose from how do you ever nail anything down in pictures? The answer is, more often than not, to simply draw a dull, vaguely shaped (usually contractible!) blob. Despite not illustrating any features worthy of interest, this is often enough as a base to investigate certain ideas (such as coning, suspension etc.). Of course once you become interested in homotopy, perhaps you start considering a blob with some nonzero genus, so that you can see more interesting behaviour of loops and such.

In general it comes down to a tradeoff between faithfully representing the concept on the page, and actually ending up with a simple and easy to look at diagram. But I would say that even a too-specific diagram is far better than no picture at all, as long as one is careful to keep the proviso in mind that things need not be exactly that way.